# How to call an entrypoint from the current contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, archetype

There is a [straightforward example](https://archetype-lang.org/docs/reference/instructions/operation/#call-current-contract) of how to do this in the docs, however it does not seem to work for me. With the following code which I basically copied straight from the docs ...

```
entry callAnotherEntryPoint() {
  effect {
    transfer 0tz to entry self.anotherEntryPoint();
  }
}

entry anotherEntryPoint() {
  effect {
    const dothings = "things done";
  }
}
```

... I get the error `unknown entry: "anotherEntryPoint"` in vscode and the typescript bindings will not build. I know that `anotherEntryPoint` isn't the problem, as I can call it successfullly with the test script. What am I missing here?

Help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The called entrypoint must be defined before the calling entrypoint:

```
entry anotherEntryPoint() {
  effect {
    const dothings = "things done";
  }
}

entry callAnotherEntryPoint() {
  effect {
    transfer 0tz to entry self.anotherEntryPoint();
  }
}
```

Comment: ‍♂️ Great thanks dzonda!